# Middleware route redirecting to homepage rather admin page

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

My middle ware should redirect me the text but it is taking me to the home page.where as without the middleware command the /admin route works well.It does pass the requirements, as in middleware if i give 'welcome' instead 'home' still it redirects me to home page,its not like for not passing the gateway it is redirecting me to the home page.

Route:

```
Route::get('/admin', function(){
    return 'you are a admin';
})->middleware(['auth','auth.admin']);
```

Middleware:

```
if(Auth::user()->hasAnyRole('admin')){
         return $next($request);
}
return redirect('home');}
```

route list

[image]

Comment: it this issue after you log in.?

Comment: no from the very begining it is redirecting to home page.

Comment: sorry didn't get u

Comment: i mean yes.i didnt get your question first.i am very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any route named as `welcome` or anything else apart from `home` and `login`
Create a view and make a route to access it.Then update that route in the middleware method.

```
if(Auth::user()->hasAnyRole('admin')){
   return $next($request);
 }
   return redirect('newroute');
}
```

It'll work then

Comment: Route::get('/admin', function(){
    return 'you are a admin';
})->middleware(['auth','auth.admin']); i have done this before./admin rute it should hit but it is hitting home route